# Can one create custom emotions to match a person's facial expression?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I have 6 images to use for comparison.

These are levels of pain.

[image] No Hurt

[image: Hurts a little] Hurts a little bit

[image] Hurts a little more

[image: Hurts even more] Hurts even more

[image: Hurts a lot] Hurts a lot

[image: Hurts worst] Hurts worst

Is it possible to analyze an image to see it there is a close match to these>

Comment: The Custom Vision API may be a good candidate for this scenario.

Comment: Not related to your question, but I feel like your 'no hurt' and 'hurts a little bit' images should be the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the values returned in JSON format from [Emotion API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/emotion/) and categorize using conditions on your side, or use [Custom Vision API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/)